# Связь базы данных и сайта

Tags: база-данных

Вопрос может быть не относится к данному направлению форума. Но может, кто знает - в интернете искал - бессмысленно. Суть вот в чем: в нашем городе есть магазин (букинист); он относится к Министерству культуры РФ. У них есть база данных и они хотят сделать на ее базе сайт. Хотелось бы узнать, министерство культуры вообще щедрое подразделение или скорее скупое? И еще. Как можно связать БД и сайт с каталогом продукции? В смысле добавляется товар в БД и чтоб он сразу отображался на сайте? Для этого не нужно хранить всю базу на хостинге? ( А она ого-го какая). Или возможно, чтоб сайт сам проникал в их БД, хранящуюся на их компе, черпал информацию и показывал ее? Просто не знаю возможно ли это...
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

"У них есть база данных" - 1С? Если да, то 1С поддерживает выгрузку данных в MySQL. В 7.7 такое делала...

Comment: Боюсь, что не 1С. Они сами не знают, какая база. Две бабульки сидят - а документация - в минкульте, а чтобы ее получить, надо кучу запросов сделать. Просто теоретически такое возможно? И сколько примерно такая разработка будет стоить?

Comment: Возможно, конечно. Цены будут зависеть от ваших запросов и  "жадности"  местных разработчиков :)

Comment: Ну а на глаз сколько?

Comment: 1) Лучше, чтобы комп с БД сам загружал базу/обновления на сайт, например в виде файлов по фтп.
2) Требуется реализовать импорт из файлов в базу данных сайта в определёные промежутки времени
3) Создать сайт(CMS бесплатная? или платная?) с дизайном.
4) Ещё ТЗ придётся писать, а это тоже значительные затраты времени.


По ценам по моему мнению 50к-100к рублей. Может быть и больше.

Answer (score 0):

Я б посоветовал хранить выгружать и хранить базу на хостинге и сделать скрипт обновления ежесуточный, скажем и принудительный, если вдруг чего в течении дня надо оперативно поменять.
С 1с можно напрямую работать без выгрузок, там MsSQL. Реализовывали такой проект. В базе делалась нужная "вьюшка", а к ней уже с сайта шёл запрос.